# Login with Paypal javascript integration

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am trying to integrate the new Login with Paypal feature using javascript. I am able to get the button work easily but when I try to get the access token using the authorization code, it does not work and always return: **{"error_description":"client id or secret is null","error":"invalid_client"}**. Based on the error, I know what it the problem, but no matter what I try, it just did not work.

I am able to make it work with the following curl code

```
curl -v https://api.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice \
-u "bf4a9e849b21a1feb85f161aaa4f2cea:dfff866aa76de7c6" \
-d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=6Aam6hMOrHl4v7l...sv16l&redirect_uri=http://somedomain.com/myapp/return.php"
```

Below are one of my post code:

```
var path = "https://api.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice";
var code = $("#txtCode").val();
path = path + "?grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com&code="+code;
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    datatype: "json",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic urlencoded-base64encoded-client_id-secret'},
    data: JSON.stringify({}),
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Updated: reference document page:  https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#grant-token-from-authorization-code