# Paypal login with cURL and JavaScript + RestAPI

Tags: javascript, html, curl, paypal

I'd like to login to a web app using paypal, and retrieve the information of the account, i'm using RestApi but i can't make that login with javascript, and i don't know why?

I've checked their documentation, but didn't make it.

I've used this post as well, but no solution found: [Login with Paypal javascript integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901006/login-with-paypal-javascript-integration)

Can anyone point me to an example already made or give hint to make this.

I can't understand the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span id="btn-login"></span>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/api.js"></script>
<script>
paypal.use( ["login"], function(login) {
  login.render ({
    "appid": "AXpyxRAJ3V0Jb6x5Vt8aEu6HK0PvqLk188J1e6fXCW5qmTm570eOdSQUJ7o2",
    "authend": "sandbox",
    "scopes": "profile email address phone https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes",
    "containerid": "btn-login",
    "locale": "pt-pt",
    "returnurl": "http://severianos-box.com/mybox/market.html"
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Log In with PayPal button JavaScript code builder](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/identity/button-js-builder/)  helps with localizing or customizing the Log In with PayPal button; additionally, the authorization endpoint and its parameters are dynamically generated from the information entered in this form. Try using it to generate your script.

Comment: but how can i auto_redirect parent page, it redirects in popup window.?? :(